# Chrome extension: Add style to element if it contains particular text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dom, innerhtml

I want to add styling to an element only if it contains a particular string. i.e. if(el contains str) {el:style}.

If I wanted just the links containing **w3.org** to be pink, how would I find  `<a href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">article < /a>` inside the innerHTML and then style the word "article" on the page.

So far, I can turn ALL the links pink but I can't selectively target the ones containing "www.w3.org".

```
var links = [...document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")];
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].style["color"] = "#FF00FF";
}
```

How would I apply this ONLY to the elements containing the string "w3.org"?

I thought this would be so simple at first! Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't filter by non-exact href values when finding the initial list, and you can't filter by contained text then either, you can filter the list after the fact using plain javascript:

```
var links = [...document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")];
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i]['href'].indexOf('www.w3.org') == -1) { continue };
  links[i].style["color"] = "#FF00FF";
}
```

Assuming you want to filter by the href, that is. If you mean the literal text, you would use `links[i]['text']` instead.

Comment: AAAHHH it worked! Thank you. It's been driving me crazy.